# glReadPixels with GL_INT type doesn't return negative values

Tags: opengl-3

I've set up a fragment shader in OpenGL to calculate YUV data, and output it to a custom Framebuffer object. After rendering I read back the YUV data to my application with glReadPixels().

When I read back the YUV as GL_FLOAT I get negative values for the V component. However when I read the same thing back as GL_INT I get only positive values. Shouldn't GL_INT give me signed integer values? Does anyone know how to get signed ints from glReadPixels()?

I'm using OpenGL 3.3, with GLFW and GLEW.

UPDATE: I also tried reading back with GL_SHORT and I was able get a **signed** 16-bit value. Maybe this is a GL implementation bug on my system. Would be interested if anyone else can reproduce this.

INITIALIZATION CODE:

```
// Color Buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbYUV);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbYUV);
glRenderbufferStorage
    (GL_RENDERBUFFER
    ,GL_RGBA32F
    ,width
    ,height
    );

// Depth Buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbDepth);
glRenderbufferStorage
    (GL_RENDERBUFFER
    ,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24
    ,width
    ,height
    );

glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebufferObj);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferObj);

// Bind Color and Depth Renderbuffers to the Framebuffer object
glFramebufferRenderbuffer
    (GL_FRAMEBUFFER
    ,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
    ,GL_RENDERBUFFER
    ,rbYUV
    );
glFramebufferRenderbuffer
    (GL_FRAMEBUFFER
    ,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT
    ,GL_RENDERBUFFER
    ,rbDepth
    );
```

RENDER LOOP:

```
// Set up stuff to be rendered...
glDrawArrays(...);
glFlush();

glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadPixels
    (0, 0
    ,width
    ,height
    ,GL_RGBA
    ,GL_FLOAT
    ,p_YUV_float_out
    );
// p_YUV_float_out looks fine
// e.g. "0.49769023  0.085087359  -0.071942836  1.0000000"


glReadPixels
    (0, 0
    ,width
    ,height
    ,GL_RGBA
    ,GL_INT
    ,p_YUV_int_out
    );
// p_YUV_int_out is ok for Y and U, but V isn't negative
// e.g. "1068793704  182719944  309065418 2147483647"
// hex  "3fb47f68 0ae415c8 126bf6ca 7fffffff"
```

Answer (score 0):

WAG here, you might want to look at http://docs.gl/gl3/glPixelStore which by http://docs.gl/gl3/glReadPixels ~"controls the processing of the pixel data before it is placed into client memory"